# why does initializing subclasses require calling the super class's same init function?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, subclass, superclass

I have heard that when you have a subclass, you are supposed to initialize the superclass with the same init function from within the subclass's init.  What I mean is that the subclass's init should call [super init] and the subclass's initWithFrame should call [super initWithFrame].  Why is this?  Why does calling the super's init from a subclass's initWithFrame result in an infinite loop?

If this is required, then does this mean I can't create a new init function within a subclass such as initWithPoint and have that call super's init or initWithFrame simply because the super class doesn't have initWithPoint?  I guess the heart of the question here is simply why it's improper to call a different super class, something that's confusing me possibly because of my c++ background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a subclass, if you implement an initializer, then you must be sure to call the superclass's designated initializer(s), and you must provide at least one designated initializer of your own, though this can just be your override of the superclass's.

As part of initializing your subclass, you must call one of the superclass's designated initializers.

A class's documentation should nominate its designated initializers. If not, the designated initializer is generally assumed to be the most specific initializer (the one taking the most arguments) provided by the superclass.

For further details, see ["The Objective-C Programming Language: Allocating and Initializing Objects."](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-105377) *[Note: As of December 2013, this content no longer appears to be available via Apple's doc center. What was a language reference has been replaced by more task-oriented tutorials and conceptual documentation.]*

As to your specific questions:

**Why is this?** So that the superclass has a chance to initialize its state. You can then go ahead and initialize the state you add above and beyond what the superclass provides.

**Why does calling the super's init from a subclass's initWithFrame result in an infinite loop?** Because, for `NSView`, `-init` is not the designated initializer, though it is `NSObject`'s. So `NSView` overrides it to call its designated initializer, `-initWithFrame:`. If you've called `-init` from your `-initWithFrame:`, you now have `-initWithFrame:` calling `-init` calling `-initWithFrame:` calling `-init:` calling…

**Does this mean…?** No, because this is not required. You must understand the actual documentation, not hearsay.

Comment: I tried viewing the contents of the link provided to verify your first paragraph, the link is not working.
However here is my argument: "must override the superclass's designated initializer(s)" sounds unnecessary (and therefore sounds untrue). Take for example a subclass of UIView called "NamedUIView" where I simply add an NSString property called name. I can simply do: NamedUIView *myView = [[NamedUIView alloc] init]; [myView setName: @"JeremysView"]. And that will be perfectly fine. I do not need to override UIView's init method in NamedUIView's .m file since there is nothing to add into it

Comment: Yeah, Apple likes to play hide-and-go-seek with their URLs. They don't seem to have anything equivalent to the original document any more; they used to have a language spec, but now they just have tutorials. I've edited the answer to clarify when you need to override.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this? Why does calling the super's init from a subclass's initWithFrame result in an infinite loop?

If the `-init` in super is implemented as

```
-(id)init {
  return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

then the call graph will loop around:

```
[subclass initWithFrame:]
   |     ^
   v     |
[super init]
```

as `self` always uses the current class ("subclass").

---

> If this is required, then does this mean I can't create a new init function within a subclass such as initWithPoint and have that call super's init or initWithFrame simply because the super class doesn't have initWithPoint?

No this is not required. What is preferred is to call `super`'s most specialized initializer, so there's no chance super's `-initXXX` calls back the subclass's `-initYYY`.

Comment: This is the best explanation of the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does calling the super's init from a subclass's initWithFrame result in an infinite loop?

Coming from a C++ background as you say you do, the main problem is probably that you are used to the C++ method calling paradigm.  In Objective-C, you do not call functions of objects.  It's not even technically completely correct to say you invoke methods.  In Objective-C, you send messages to objects and the object decides what to do with them.  What it normally does is look up a method in its class and invoke that.  The consequence of that is that you cannot control which version of a method in a class hierarchy gets invoked by a message.  It's always the method belonging to the class of the object you send the message to (except in one case).  It's as if C++ had no non virtual functions, not even the constructors.

The one exception to this is when you send a message to super.  In that case, the method on your class is bypassed.  This can lead to infinite loops as you have found out.  The reason is because we don't call functions, we send messages.  So if methodA in class SubKlass sends `[super methodB]` the implementation of methodB in Klass will be invoked.  If it then sends `[self methodA]` self is still an instance of SubKlass, it hasn't magically transformed into an instance of Klass, so methodA in SubKlass will be invoked.

This is why the rules for initialisers seem so convoluted.  Only the designated initialiser is guaranteed not to send one of the other initialisers so you can only safely send the designated initialiser to super in your initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

from a c++ perspective:

> I have heard that when you have a subclass, you are supposed to initialize the superclass with the same init function from within the subclass's init. What I mean is that the subclass's init should call [super init] and the subclass's initWithFrame should call [super initWithFrame].

that's not true. it's merely common. you are free to call any superclass initializer that is documented as a valid initializer.

it may help to view it like this:
look at the superclass' initalizers and determine which are supported.

- sometimes there is a designated initializer
- sometimes there are new initializers (e.g., one which may add an argument to the super-superclass)
- sometimes there are intializers inherited from the super-superclass

for designated initializers: consider it protected

for new initializer: consider it protected

for inherited initializers: *typically* consider private when the superclass declares new initializers, otherwise protected

> Why does calling the super's init from a subclass's initWithFrame result in an infinite loop?

such is the effect (undefined behavior) of calling an intializer which you should not call.

> If this is required, then does this mean I can't create a new init function within a subclass such as initWithPoint and have that call super's init or initWithFrame simply because the super class doesn't have initWithPoint?

this is fine as long as you call through one of the supported superclass initializers.

> I guess the heart of the question here is simply why it's improper to call a different super class, something that's confusing me possibly because of my c++ background?

objc doesn't support hiding/visibility for initializers. once it's in a superclass' interface, it's there (and you're able to make bad choices where the compiler can't help you) - you're expected to determine the visibility graph for initializers and write your subclass accordingly. objc is lacking language features that you're accustomed to having in c++.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you heard it from, but AFAIK it's not required. You can choose to init your subclass with whatever you want, provided that you call an init method of the superclass. Any init method will work.

However, if you also have the same init function in your superclass, I think the better thing to do is to call that function, then add your own customization. It's not required, it's just good practice to do so, because that init function may provide some initializations and settings that you may forget to add.