# Super in initializing objects

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, super

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why does initializing subclasses require calling the super class's same init function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002919/why-does-initializing-subclasses-require-calling-the-super-classs-same-init-func)

I really can't understand the role of **super** in initializing an object.
For example, having this (example — not written by me) code:

```
@implementation MyObject
  - (id) init
  {
     if([super init]){
       return self;
     } else {
       return nil;
     }
  }
  @end
```

What [super init] actually does? I'm confused, can't get the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to ensure correct initialisation of inherited instance variables from the super class of `MyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Objective-C is object oriented you can inherit from other classes. When you inherit from other classes you can intercept messages and get to decide if you pass them on to the class you inherit from. In the case of init it is almost **always** important to do `self = [super init]` or use the designated init method of the class to make sure the object is created correctly. Imagine if in MyObject in your init method you create an `NSMutableArray` that your class uses but init was never called because someone else inherited from your class and never called `[super init]`. You would then have nil references or either a bad pointer every where you attempted to used your `NSMutableArray`. The reason why it is important to set `self` equal to `[super init]` is the value of self may change such as in error recovery.

```
//this is valid
-(id)init
{
   if((self = [super init]))
   {
       if(someInitializationFails)
       {
           [self release];
           self = nil;
       }
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: You referring to me leaving out the necessity of `if((self = [super init]))`? It looks like the poster understood the conditional but I can edit.

Comment: Yup -- someone is bound to copypasta that without thinking...

Answer (score 0):

Wil Shipley recommends [this](http://wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/self-stupid-init.html) (from 2009):

```
- (id)init;
{
 if (!(self = [super init]))
   return nil;

 // other stuff
 return self;
}
```

But why assign super init's return to self?

Matt Gallagher's [article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/what-does-it-mean-when-you-assign-super.html) attempts to explain it...

-- Quote:

> If you remember back at the start, I
>   said that the initWithString: part of
>   a typical [[MyClass alloc]
>   initWithString:@"someString"]
>   invocation is converted into an
>   objc_msgSend call:

```
MyClass *myObject2 = objc_msgSend(myObject1, initSelector, @"someString");
```

> So by the time we get
>   to the inside of the method, self
>   already has a value; its value is
>   **myObject1** (i.e. the allocated object,
>   as returned from the [MyClass alloc]
>   call. This is essential because
>   without it, the super invocation
>   wouldn't be possible — the self value
>   is used by the compiler to send the
>   invocation:

```
[super init];
```

> becomes:

```
objc_msgSendSuper(self, @selector(init));
```

> Yes, **self** already
>   has a value when your initializer
>   starts. In fact, it is almost
>   guaranteed to be the correct, final
>   value.

-- Unquote

Essentially, I think a lot of people are left confused as to what each init method's 'self' is pointing to exactly, up through the superclass chain.

The answer to this riddle is implied in Apple's [Objective-C Programming Language doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW2), under the section titled Designated Initializers:

> Note that B version of init sends a
>   message to self to invoke the
>   initWithName: method. Therefore, when
>   the receiver is an instance of the B
>   class, it invokes the B version of
>   initWithName:, and when the receiver
>   is an instance of the C class, it
>   invokes the C version.

Or, in other words, the 'self' variable points to the our instance that is being initialized. Again to reemphasize, all of these init methods up through the superclass chain are inherited by our instance, and as such, the 'self' variable in them points to our instance (unless explicitly changed) .

Am I right? Of course!