# Why super doesn't need to get allocated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, allocation, init, super

We always `alloc` before `init` in Objective C, then while writing `init` method, Why we don't `alloc` a `super` and then initiate it?

```
- (id) init {
   if(self = [super init]){
      //init iVars
   }
   return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the child interface is allocated, its size includes the size of the parent. They aren't separate objects, they're combined. 'super' must be initialized so it can prepare its data members. Your object then initializes its members. For example, lets say you had a custom reference counting interface that needs to initialize 'refCnt' to 1. You then base your interface on that interface. That means your interface's allocation size is the size of the reference counting interface + the size of your specific contributions. (e.g., 'int refCnt' in the reference counting interface and 'int x' in your interface means sizeof(your interface)==8~.) So, the allocation only needs to occur once. Then, you initialize 'super' (the reference counting interface, in this situation) so 'refCnt' will be 1. After that, you initialize your own data.

Comment: Note that `super` is not a separate object. It just means "self, but using the superclass's implementation of the named method".

Answer (score 3):

Because "alloc" already allocates the space for the object you're instantiating.

Your subclass doesn't need to allocate (separate) space for a base class.

You also might find some useful information in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002919/why-does-initializing-subclasses-require-calling-the-super-classs-same-init-fun).